# Formating String to Date in Android, but Result date is not OK

Tags: android, date, formatting

In the app, I have done that the user choose some date and time with DAte and Time PickerFragments.

When the choose the date , I put it in TextViews. after that I need to verify that the dates that the user choose are correct. I mean, the end date can't be before that the start date.

To test that the conversion is doing OK I have donde this code:

```
String start_date = (String) tv_start_date.getText();
String end_date = (String) tv_end_date.getText();
String start_hour = (String) tv_start_hour.getText();
String end_hour = (String) tv_end_hour.getText();
String auxiliar = start_date  + " " + start_hour;
String auxiliar2 = end_date + " " + end_hour;

SimpleDateFormat sdf_aux = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy hh:mm");

Date auuuux = sdf_aux.parse(auxiliar);
Date auuuux2 = sdf_aux.parse(auxiliar2);

Log.d("Meeting", "Inicio: Start--> "+auuuux.toString());
Log.d("Meeting", "FIN: END--> "+auuuux2.toString());
```

But when I see the Log, I can see that the date, is not correct:

Few Images:

[image]
[image]

Log:

```
03-26 13:25:27.657: D/Meeting(15255): Start--> Mon Jan 26 13:25:00 CET 2015
03-26 13:25:27.657: D/Meeting(15255): END--> Tue Jan 27 14:26:00 CET 2015
```

As you can see, today is Thursday 26/3/15 , but if you see the log it says that is Monday!

How can I fix it?
I have done somthing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have put the wrong String in Your date Format:

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf_aux = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy hh:mm");
```

it must be:

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf_aux = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy hh:mm");
```

because the capital M is for month, the small for Minutes...

### EDIT

To get the time in 24 hour format, You have to change the h to H:

```
  SimpleDateFormat sdf_aux = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm");
```

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Oooookk......... never mind that was important.. One more thing..I have realised that  if I put for example 12.05  it converts like  --> 00:05:00, but thats wronkg to, because I want 12h of the morning, not night... some fix?

Comment: @Shudy Scroll down to the date and time patterns table [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Oh yes, I have made same mistakes at the beginning :) ...look into API at the Time pattern syntax, You´ll need it...: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @Opiatefuchs yeap, I have seen the problem. I wrote before see the new comments with the links. I had to change the "hh" to "HH". So it will be like : `SimpleDateFormat sdf_aux = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm");`.   Thanks for all!!! This I'll pin it to my knowledge ^^